# I can’t figure out why my hamburger menu won’t work

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, hamburger-menu

I can’t figure out why my hamburger menu doesn’t work. Here is the link to the [site](https://gianttripod.github.io/MannyRamosPhotography/) and the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/GiantTripod/MannyRamosPhotography).

```js
let MainNav = document.getElementById("js-menu");
let navBarToggle = document.getElementById("js-navbar-toggle");

navBarToggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  MainNav.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.header-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script';
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #3d3c38;
  color: #f5f4f2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.header-title {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  justify-self: flex-start;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header-nav {
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-top: 7rem;
}

.header-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f5f4f2;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.media-icons {
  justify-self: flex-end;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-top: auto;
  align-self: center;
}

.media-icons i {
  margin-left: .5rem;
}

.media-icons p {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.header-name1,
.header-name2 {
  margin: 0 .5rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.header-image {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 12rem;
  border: none;
  justify-self: flex-start;
  align-self: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .site-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "header-container" "main-container";
  }

  .header-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-left: .8rem;
    margin-right: .5rem;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    height: 1.5rem;
  }

  .header-image {
    display: none;
  }

  .header-name1,
  .header-name2 {
    display: none;
  }

  .header-container p {
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar-toggle {
    display: initial;
    margin-right: auto;
    align-self: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 150%;
  }

  .Navbar__ToggleShow {
    display: block;
  }

  .header-nav {
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }

  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: none;
  }

  .media-icons {
    margin-left: auto;
    font-size: 75%;
    align-self: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="site-container">
  <header class="header-container">
    <img src="pictures/IMG_2535.JPG" alt="header-image" class="header-image">
    <div class="header-title">
      <h1 class="header-name1">Manny Ramos</h1>
      <h2 class="header-name2">Photography</h2>
    </div>

    <nav class="header-nav">
      <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </span>
      <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">home.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">portfolio.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">about me.</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="media-icons">
      <p class="email">manny@email.com</p>
      <p class="phone-number">(123)456-7890</p>
      <i class="fab fa-instagram icons fa-3x"></i>
      <i class="icon fas fa-underline icons fa-3x"></i>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212) — in short: no. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself, as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212)_), along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Comment: Replacing the selector `.active` by `.main-nav.active` may result in the correct specificity. There are other issues though. Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser, e.g. the Inspector to see how CSS rules are applied.

Comment: @SebastianSimon i've reformatted the question. also if I replaced the .active how would i change the script?

Comment: Also the grid setup might be getting broken in the snippet so here's the link.

[link](https://gianttripod.github.io/MannyRamosPhotography/)

Comment: Please try this css it may be help for you. .main-nav.active {display: block;}

Comment: When running the debugger for the nav script i'm getting this error: VM9605:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'MainNav' has already been declared.
but its targeting the line that MainNav is originally declared. have ideas?
@SebastianSimon

Comment: @jaydeeppatel that worked but now the hamburger menu disappears when active so I can't toggle and I have to reload the page. Any ideas?

Comment: @chrisMcGrath It's overlapping issue, Please add this css .main-nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

Comment: @jaydeeppatel So I added it but nothing changed. I seriously can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. This is so frustrating sometimes

Comment: @jaydeeppatel alright i think ive figured out how to get it to work but now i can't figure out how to get the "main-container" grid container to react to the nav when its active. i tried messing with the margins for everything i can think of. have any ideas on what i can try? all code has been updated if you want to look at it

Comment: Hi chris McGrath, your Hamberger is working only u need to change the color of ".header-nav a" to black for the mobile site.

Comment: Thank you guys! Yea I have to change the font and figure out why everything in the heading moves when you click it. But thanks for the help!